# .OrderBy in Linq query not always ordering properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4.1

Below is a Linq query I'm using in my ASP MVC 3 controller to try and order the results alphabetically by state code. 99% of the time this works just fine, but I'm finding a couple lists that are unordered like so

[image]

For each bank that we list in the index, I need to pull from a secondary table `BankListAgentId` and display all the agents we have working with that particular bank. The majority of the time the agents are ordered according to state code properly, but a few times they wind up unordered like in the screen shot above.

```
foreach (var bank in banklist)
{
    bank.BankListAgentId = (from a in db.BankListAgentId
                            where a.BankID == bank.ID
                           select a).OrderBy(x => x.StateCode, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried separating out the operations into individual lines like so, but got the same results (99% ordered properly, 1% not)

```
foreach (var bank in banklist)
{
    var agent = (from a in db.BankListAgentId
                 where a.BankID == bank.ID
                 select a).ToList();

    agent = agent.OrderBy(x => x.StateCode).ToList();

    bank.BankListAgentId = agent.ToList();
}
```

Comment: So the screenshot above is of bank.BankListAgentId or bank?

Comment: Just to be sure, I would consume the db query and only then do `OrderBy` and back to `List`.

Comment: @ysrb: it is of the `bank.BankListAgentID`. I added a better description to the post. thx

Comment: @YoryeNathan: I assume you meant separating those into individual operations. I added what I did to my post, however I received the same results.

Comment: After edit: you did not consume the db IEnumerable. Add another `.ToList()` before the `OrderBy`.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by 'consume' the IEnumerable. Just posted what I think you meant.

Comment: That's the `.ToList()`. The new edit it what I meant, except that there is no need to do `ToList()` after already doing so. Screenshot the list before and after `OrderBy(...).ToList()`.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: oops, just saw typo in my previous edit. Fixed to how it looks in the controller

Comment: Did you verify that the problem is not in your view? For example by checking the returned collection in the debugger if it is sorted or not. Your "Edit" code is technically very different (sorting in memory) to the original code (sorting in database). Hard to imagine that two technologies (SQL Server and .NET) are unable to sort correctly.

Comment: @NealR Are you sure you didn't append new bank to the banklist after the loop?

Comment: Have you check if there are blank charters at end or start of the values ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your OrderBy() is on the inside of the foreach(var bank in banklist) loop, it will affect each individual query only as it runs in each iteration.  You need an OrderBy clause to occur after all queries have finished.

Try something like this instead:

banklist.SelectMany(bank => bank.BankListAgentId).OrderBy(a => a.StateCode, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();